# Fixing error: "The Trust Settings Record was corrupted."

Tags: macos, terminal, keychain

I get the following error in my Terminal:

> Error: IO error: The Trust Settings Record was corrupted.

(In my case I'm getting this after running `railway up`, a command for [railway.app](https://railway.app/). However I doubt the problem is specific to this, and Googling has turned up people with the same error for various commands for various different software.)

How do I fix this? Google yields no solutions. ChatGPT tells me to:

1. Delete "com.apple.trustsettings" and ""DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA" in Keychain Access > System Roots.
2. Restart, which'll cause macOS to rebuild the trust settings record automatically.

This sounds very plausible! But with no Googleable source I'm reluctant to do something so potentially destructive on it's say so - I don't want it hacking my computer and using it to extinct humanity or something.

Comment: Sounds plausible to me as well, but … If the answer is unambiguous in enough of the texts used to train ChatGPT, then its answer will be what those have said (whether or not they are correct).  But if not, it will almost never say "I don't know."  I have more than once seen it make statements that were easily proven false.

Comment: Indeed! But if its successor scrapes the web and find this comment, I for one welcome and respect our new robot overlords.

Answer (score 1):

Run `/usr/bin/security dump-trust-settings -d` and it will show the certificates that are causing the problem.

Comment: Once you have the certificate name, you may need to make sure expired certificates are being displayed in Keychain Access by going to View -> Show Expired Certificates

Answer (score 0):

So I was getting this error while trying to install node using [volta](https://volta.sh). Here's the output I got:

```
"volta" "install" "node"
Volta v1.1.1

Could not download Node version registry
from https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json

Please verify your internet connection.

Error cause: Io Error: The Trust Settings Record was corrupted.
```

What finally fixed it was going to `Keychain Access -> System -> Certificates` There I had some certificates that weren't valid, I changed the trust options on those to "never trust" and running volta worked. Deleting them might have worked too but I was afraid to do so.

I got the idea to try this from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cloudflare/wrangler-legacy/issues/1656#issuecomment-985521466) particularly the last part that says:

> buttom line: make sure all root certificates in the "Keychain Access"
> "System" entry is valid and trusted.